# Custom Sort in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have a list

```
["usd", "aed", "afn", "all", "amd", "ang", "aoa", "ars", "aud", "awg", "azn", "bam", "bbd", "bdt", "bgn", "bif", "bmd", "bnd", "bob", "brl", "bsd", "bwp", "bzd", "cad", "cdf", "chf", "clp", "cny", "cop", "crc", "cve", "czk", "djf", "dkk", "dop", "dzd", "eek", "egp", "etb", "eur", "fjd", "fkp", "gbp", "gel", "gip", "gmd", "gnf", "gtq", "gyd", "hkd", "hnl", "hrk", "htg", "huf", "idr", "ils", "inr", "isk", "jmd", "jpy", "kes", "kgs", "khr", "kmf", "krw", "kyd", "kzt", "lak", "lbp", "lkr", "lrd", "lsl", "ltl", "lvl", "mad", "mdl", "mga", "mkd", "mnt", "mop", "mro", "mur", "mvr", "mwk", "mxn", "myr", "mzn", "nad", "ngn", "nio", "nok", "npr", "nzd", "pab", "pen", "pgk", "php", "pkr", "pln", "pyg", "qar", "ron", "rsd", "rub", "rwf", "sar", "sbd", "scr", "sek", "sgd", "shp", "sll", "sos", "srd", "std", "svc", "szl", "thb", "tjs", "top", "try", "ttd", "twd", "tzs", "uah", "ugx", "uyu", "uzs", "vnd", "vuv", "wst", "xaf", "xcd", "xof", "xpf", "yer", "zar", "zmw"]
```

A default_currency, let's say EUR 
A last_currency used, let's say CAD

I want  my list sorted with this criteria

- last currency is used is first
- default currency after
- USD, EUR,CAD after
- and the rest

Is there any way to achieve this ? (One liner if possible)

bolo

Comment: assume you don't want a currency in the result twice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
last_currency = 'cad'
default_currency = 'eur'
primary_currencies = [last_currency, default_currency, 'usd', 'eur', 'cad'].uniq
all_currencies = ["usd", "aed", "afn", "all", "amd", "ang", "aoa", "ars", "aud", "awg", "azn", "bam", "bbd", "bdt", "bgn", "bif", "bmd", "bnd", "bob", "brl", "bsd", "bwp", "bzd", "cad", "cdf", "chf", "clp", "cny", "cop", "crc", "cve", "czk", "djf", "dkk", "dop", "dzd", "eek", "egp", "etb", "eur", "fjd", "fkp", "gbp", "gel", "gip", "gmd", "gnf", "gtq", "gyd", "hkd", "hnl", "hrk", "htg", "huf", "idr", "ils", "inr", "isk", "jmd", "jpy", "kes", "kgs", "khr", "kmf", "krw", "kyd", "kzt", "lak", "lbp", "lkr", "lrd", "lsl", "ltl", "lvl", "mad", "mdl", "mga", "mkd", "mnt", "mop", "mro", "mur", "mvr", "mwk", "mxn", "myr", "mzn", "nad", "ngn", "nio", "nok", "npr", "nzd", "pab", "pen", "pgk", "php", "pkr", "pln", "pyg", "qar", "ron", "rsd", "rub", "rwf", "sar", "sbd", "scr", "sek", "sgd", "shp", "sll", "sos", "srd", "std", "svc", "szl", "thb", "tjs", "top", "try", "ttd", "twd", "tzs", "uah", "ugx", "uyu", "uzs", "vnd", "vuv", "wst", "xaf", "xcd", "xof", "xpf", "yer", "zar", "zmw"]

primary_currencies + (all_currencies - primary_currencies)
```

Output:

```
["cad", "eur", "usd", "aed", "afn", "all", "amd", "ang", "aoa", "ars", "aud", "awg", "azn", "bam", "bbd", "bdt", "bgn", "bif", "bmd", "bnd", "bob", "brl", "bsd", "bwp", "bzd", "cdf", "chf", "clp", "cny", "cop", "crc", "cve", "czk", "djf", "dkk", "dop", "dzd", "eek", "egp", "etb", "fjd", "fkp", "gbp", "gel", "gip", "gmd", "gnf", "gtq", "gyd", "hkd", "hnl", "hrk", "htg", "huf", "idr", "ils", "inr", "isk", "jmd", "jpy", "kes", "kgs", "khr", "kmf", "krw", "kyd", "kzt", "lak", "lbp", "lkr", "lrd", "lsl", "ltl", "lvl", "mad", "mdl", "mga", "mkd", "mnt", "mop", "mro", "mur", "mvr", "mwk", "mxn", "myr", "mzn", "nad", "ngn", "nio", "nok", "npr", "nzd", "pab", "pen", "pgk", "php", "pkr", "pln", "pyg", "qar", "ron", "rsd", "rub", "rwf", "sar", "sbd", "scr", "sek", "sgd", "shp", "sll", "sos", "srd", "std", "svc", "szl", "thb", "tjs", "top", "try", "ttd", "twd", "tzs", "uah", "ugx", "uyu", "uzs", "vnd", "vuv", "wst", "xaf", "xcd", "xof", "xpf", "yer", "zar", "zmw"]
```

It won't rearrange the rest of currencies.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the custom sort here. Just slap the things together (sort the main array, though, if you want) and `uniq` will take care of the duplicates.

```
def sort_but_not_really_sort(default, last, important)
  # TODO: pre-sort this
  all_currencies = ["usd", "aed", "afn", "all", "amd", "ang", "aoa", "ars", "aud", "awg", "azn", "bam", "bbd", "bdt", "bgn", "bif", "bmd", "bnd", "bob", "brl", "bsd", "bwp", "bzd", "cad", "cdf", "chf", "clp", "cny", "cop", "crc", "cve", "czk", "djf", "dkk", "dop", "dzd", "eek", "egp", "etb", "eur", "fjd", "fkp", "gbp", "gel", "gip", "gmd", "gnf", "gtq", "gyd", "hkd", "hnl", "hrk", "htg", "huf", "idr", "ils", "inr", "isk", "jmd", "jpy", "kes", "kgs", "khr", "kmf", "krw", "kyd", "kzt", "lak", "lbp", "lkr", "lrd", "lsl", "ltl", "lvl", "mad", "mdl", "mga", "mkd", "mnt", "mop", "mro", "mur", "mvr", "mwk", "mxn", "myr", "mzn", "nad", "ngn", "nio", "nok", "npr", "nzd", "pab", "pen", "pgk", "php", "pkr", "pln", "pyg", "qar", "ron", "rsd", "rub", "rwf", "sar", "sbd", "scr", "sek", "sgd", "shp", "sll", "sos", "srd", "std", "svc", "szl", "thb", "tjs", "top", "try", "ttd", "twd", "tzs", "uah", "ugx", "uyu", "uzs", "vnd", "vuv", "wst", "xaf", "xcd", "xof", "xpf", "yer", "zar", "zmw"].sort

  [last, default, *important, *all_currencies].uniq
end



default_currency = 'eur'
last_currency = 'cad'

important_currencies = ['usd', 'eur', 'cad']

sort_but_not_really_sort(default_currency, last_currency, important_currencies).take(5)
# => ["cad", "eur", "usd", "aed", "afn"]
```

Answer (score -3):

Yes, it's possible to achieve this in a one liner.

```
a = [ 'usd', 'aed', ... 'zmw' ]

a.sort{|a,b| <sorting code goes here> }
```

sort takes a block, and within that block, a and b are two adacent elements in the list that is being sorted.  Compare them, returning -1 if a should appear before b and 1 if b should appear before a, and 0 if they should remain unaffected.

Good luck.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question, does it? :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev it was intended to give him the necessary framework with which to solve his problem, not to solve it for him.

Comment: Doing this with sort block is a terrible idea. Will make for some ugly and error-prone code. I challenge you to prove me wrong :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev He said as a one liner - I indicated it's possible - I didn't say *I*'d do it that way ;)